# Definite article: the; a method of the extraction of minerals vs a method of mineral extraction

Tags: definite-article

In my mother's tongue, there is no articles; a, an, and the. 
So I am always confusing the usage of articles.

For example, the first sentence use 'the' in front of extraction, but the second does not; (the) mineral extraction

1. a method of THE extraction of minerals
2. a method of (blank) mineral extraction

These sentences are supposed to be written for the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence would be more natural to me with *for* instead of *of*. Either way, it doesn't need an article either, but is more natural with it.

There are rules you can learn that give you a clear idea of when you *must* use an article, and when you *mustn't*, but there's a lot in between - where it's strictly optional, or where it changes the meaning in subtle or not-so-subtle ways.

A major difference between your two phrases is the way in which the noun phrase related to extracting minerals is constructed. In one, you refine *extraction* with a preposition, *of*. I would say this is having a genitive role in this case (though the different roles of *of* can be subtle to distinguish), meaning that it is broad equivalent to "minerals' extraction". The second case uses an *attributive noun* to refine *extraction*, indicating that it is concerned with minerals (attributive nouns are generally in the singular regardless of other considerations).

If you use a definite article in the case using an attributive noun, you would be referring to a specific case of mineral extraction. If you used an indefinite article, you would be referring to a single but non-specific case of mineral extraction. Without an article it is broader. Because there's an indefinite article in front of the whole thing, "a method", you end up with something quite complex. With "a method of the mineral extraction", you might be talking about a specific situation regarding mineral extraction (say, extracting a mineral from a given mine), where there are potentially several methods.

The use of a definite article in the first example is a pattern you see with action nouns, and I don't think it has any particular meaning. *The*, or no article, is used when you are talking about extraction in general; *an* extraction would mean a single event where something is being extracted. For example, when making an appointment at the dentist you might tell the reception "I need to make an appointment for an extraction", while a dentist learning about it might have a lecture on "the extraction of teeth", or just "extraction of teeth".

Comment: You said "The, or no article, is used when you are talking about extraction in general"==> I think that there is a subtle difference in the nuance or meaning. Do you think so? What is the difference between " a menthod of (The/no article) extraction of minerals.